# making stratification in list of triples, according to the second element of each triple

Tags: python, list, accounting

In python, I have a list of triples in the form below:

[(220, 1.0, 1),
(385, 1.0, 2),
(405, 1.0, 2),
(1276, 1.0, 6),
(1649, 1.0, 8),
(1941, 1.0, 10),
(2554, 1.0, 13),
(3123, 1.0, 16),
(2377, 0.8879465659, 12),
(500, 0.8854919047, 2),
(2435, 0.8815715038, 12),
(2151, 0.8787807797, 11),
(1888, 0.87827976, 9),
(2185, 0.8780501222, 11),
(2215, 0.8747450062, 11),
(358, 0.8724861947, 2),
(3636, 0.8716343914, 19),
(734, 0.8714647102, 3),
(1742, 0.8707242976, 9),
............]

I want to separate and count the elements of the list,  according to the second value of each triple of the list, into ten tracks:

> =0 and <0.1

> =0.1 and <0.2

> =0.2 and <0.3

> =0.3 and <0.4

> = 0.4 and <0.5

.....

> =0.8 and <0.9

> =0.9 and <=1.0

I tried to use:

```
tracks =  np.linspace(0,1,11)  #  array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
for i in range (len(tracks)-1):
    print( tracks[i], "a", tracks[i+1], ":",  sum([1 for (x,y,z) in sm_list   if y >= tracks[i]] and y < intervalos[i+1]))
```

but it returns the following error:  " NameError: name 'y' is not defined"

How can I define compound Boolean clauses to form the above list?

making :

```
tracks =  np.linspace(0,1,11)  #  array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
for i in range (len(tracks)-1):
    print( tracks[i], "a", tracks[i+1], ":",  sum([1 for (x,y,z) in sm_list   if y >= tracks[i]] ))
```

Returns no error, but returns overlapping tracks, and that's not what I need.

Comment: What is the output you are expected?

Answer (score 0):

- First note: you had a **typo** in your first example. The following will essentially get you what you wanted:

```
tracks =  np.linspace(0,1,11)  #  array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
for i in range (len(tracks)-1):
    print( tracks[i], "a", tracks[i+1], ":",  sum([1 for (x,y,z) in sm_list   if y >= tracks[i] and y < tracks[i+1]]))
```

- Why 'essentially'? Because the rightmost boundary, namely `tracks[-1]`, equals `1.0`, so `y < 1.0` will not capture those values that are `==1`. Quick and *dirty* fix: set `tracks[-1] = 1.01` before you enter the loop.

---

- Bonus: another solution to the original problem, which does not use a `for` loop, but prefers a `numpy` approach, with a bit of `pandas`: (I encourage you to run this on your data line by line and see the output for yourself; maybe you'll realize that you need only the first few lines, depending on your real purpose)

```py
numbers = [y for (x,y,z) in sm_list]  # we care only about the second number in each triple anyway
x = (np.array(numbers) * 10).astype(np.int)  # multiply by 10 and "floor" into ints in the range 0,1,2,...,10 (e.g. 0-0.9999 will be mapped to 0, 1.0-1.9999 to 1, 9.0-9.9999 to 9, and 1.0 to 10)

# Now we have a list of integers between 0 and 10, and we remain with the task of getting their histogram or counts.

# There are plenty of ways to solve this, e.g. using collections.Counter(x), but we'll use a fancier way:
s = pd.value_counts(x)  # already may be suffice for your needs
s = s.reindex(range(0,11), fill_value=0)  # try this to ensure that all values 0,1,2,...,10 have some count associated with them (namely 0) even if they did not exist in the input

if False:  # bonus: if you don't like the cell s[10] and want its value to be added into s[9], then change this 'if False' to 'if True'...
    s[9] += s[10];
    s.drop(10, inplace=True)
```